# MySQL Indexes: Why does multi-column index perform worse than single column index?

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

I am learning about indexes and I thought I'd try an experiment using the MySQL Sakila database. I have the following query:

```
SELECT title, release_year
FROM film
WHERE release_year < 2010
AND rating = 'R';
```

This is the first index I tried:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_releaseYear ON film(rating);
```

When I ran my query, MySQL EXPLAIN returned this:

[image]

EDIT: My interpretation of these results: MySQL uses the index (sorted by rating) to quickly find all 'R'-rated films, then checks the release year of every row returned by the index.

Next, I created an index on rating and release_year:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_releaseYear ON film(rating, release_year);
```

When I ran my query, MySQL EXPLAIN returned this:

[image]

EDIT: My Expectations: MySQL would use the index (sorted by rating, then release_year) to quickly find all 'R'-rated films and release_years < 2010, and only use the film table to retrieve film titles from rows returned by the index. Even though all films in the database have the same release_year, I thought sorting the index by rating then release year would perform better (or at least the same by only using the first column of the index) as the first query, since in the first query it had to check release years in random order.

Why does the first, single-column index perform better than the second, multi-column index? I thought they would perform at least the same, since rating is listed first.

There is one thing you should be aware of: **All** films in the database have a 2006 release year.

Comment: if the value for year is always the same  this don't help the second index . in contrast the check for both the column is less efficent respect the check for a single value

Comment: Over indexing on small datasets (especially larger ones) = performance issues. See answer below from Gordon. Assuming that we are dealing with a decent dataset in size - a single column in a nonclustered index is naturally going to seek or scan the data pages faster than 2 columns. Less columns = less data being copied into the index. Therefore less to filter through. See this link for more info on MYSQL indexing --> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-indexes.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 'expectations' are right.  `EXPLAIN` is imprecise; do not trust it too far.

```
WHERE release_year < 2010
  AND rating = 'R'
```

is (usually) best optimized with

```
INDEX(rating,   -- first, because it is tested with '='
      release_year)   -- last, because it is a range.
```

If you can afford to run it both ways, watching `SESSION STATUS LIKE 'Handler%'` gives you a precise view into rows read (and perhaps written to temp tables).  I discuss that technique [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#handler_counts) .  That blog also explains that the composite index is best.

Exceptions on that being best:

- Perhaps the statistics say that using an index is not worth the effort; simply scanning the table might be better.
- Perhaps extending it to be "covering" would be better.  (Not for the query in question.)
- Perhaps the `PRIMARY KEY` should be that pair of columns, or at least start with them.  This avoids bouncing between the index BTree and the Data BTree.

If the table has only a thousand rows, you may not be able to see the difference between this index, that index, or even no index.  But, if you expect the table to grow, it is best to establish the best indexes *now*, not next year in the middle of the night when your web site has a performance problem and you have forgotten the detail.

A side note...  If you tack on `ORDER BY release_year LIMIT 5`, the composite index really shines.  This is because the index can be used for all the `WHERE`, all the `ORDER BY`, and get to the `LIMIT`, and touch only 5 rows.  Almost any other scenario will need to collect lots of rows in a temp table, sort it, then peel off 5 rows.

Answer (score 5):

You have 195 rows in your table. I don't know your data structure, but it is quite likely that all the rows fit on one data page, maybe two.

Indexes are not designed for that size of data. They are designed to make queries run faster on much larger data sets. There is some overhead for using an index. For instance, MySQL needs to load both the data pages and the index pages to run the query. You probably get no savings by reducing the number of pages being read.

The moral is simple. Don't judge performance on really small queries.  Often, indexes are not needed in those cases because they have additional overhead.

Comment: My table has 1000 rows. Is that considered too small for an index?

Comment: @user2593669 . . . It depends, but an index is not necessarily needed.  In other words, an index might not help on a table of 1,000 rows whereas it would help on 1,000,000 rows.

Comment: @user2593669 - Look at it from this point of view: how big (in megabytes) is the table? Is it less than, say, 100MB? Then MySQL can probably cache it all into RAM and whatever you do on it will be instantaneous anyway. Whether or not an index is used, you won't notice it.